# error in printing inverted half hollow pyramid in C++ using for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to print the pattern of Inverted half hollow triangle and it should look like the below pattern.

```
* * * * * * 
*       *
*     *
*   *
* *
*
```

I tried the below code but am not getting the required output. I don't want to include more variables leading to complexity .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--){
        for(int j =1;j<=i; j++){
            if(i==1||i==n||j==1||j==n||j==i){
                cout<<"* ";
            }
            else{
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
* * * * * * 
*    * 
*   * 
*  * 
* * 
*
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and the correct code for solving this.

Comment: `cout<<"  ";` You used a wrong placeholder for "* ".

Comment: @S.M. I am afraid I am not able to understand. Could you please elaborate by telling me where should I place it?

Comment: Compare my cout with your one.

Comment: @S.M. Thank you so much , I got it now . Forgot to add extra space in the second cout. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem on your 2 Strings because one takes 2 "spaces" and the other just one

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(j==i || j==1 || i==n){ /*you can simplify your condition*/
                cout<<"* ";
            }
            else{
                cout<<"  "; /*2 spaces*/
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```